# how to send and receive hex data to serial port from VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, serial-port

Using vb.NET, i need to manage a device using serial port.
I use for this, SerialPortStream from Nuget. Here is the GitHub url.
https://github.com/jcurl/serialportstream

I have info from the device provider and the message format used. Shown in this image:
[Image with message format used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Qbl.png)

I open correctly port and correctly connect to device and the event for receive data from the serial port is also ok and is fired when i send something.

For receive i use this

```
Private Sub s_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles s.DataReceived
        Console.Beep()
        Console.WriteLine("<---- " & s.BytesToRead)
 End Sub
```

I know what messages i need to send and what messages i expect to receive looking logs i have from other apps running same device.

But i don't know how to format and send the messages from my app and i don't know how to manage the s_DataReceived event to get the responses from the device.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The way for send is:

```
 Dim b() As Byte = New Byte() {&H01, &H02, &H03, &H04, &H05} (and so on... once data is completed.)
 s.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
```

for receive is:

```
dataArrived = s.ReadExisting
```